# Run (and debug) typescript mocha tests in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, mocha.js, visual-studio-2019

I've got a small typescript project that utilises `mocha` for tests, written mostly in Visual Studio Code. I'm more comfortable with Visual Studio 2019 (with ReSharper) though and wanted to set up the project for use in Visual Studio (not Code).

I can debug the tests in Visual Studio Code, but would like to be able to run and debug them in Visual Studio too.

I've created a project from the existing files, but the test explorer doesn't even open and any tests I try to run seem to be run with Jasmine, which means that no tests are found. I already tried setting the test runner to mocha in the project properties and the Test root to my test directory `test\`.

My folder structure is

```
\
|--built
|--src
  |--file.ts
|--test
  |--file.tests.ts
```

How can I get Visual Studio to recognise the mocha tests?
Also, testing currently builds the project first which is rather useless when I want to test the typescript files (works well with `cross-env` and `ts-node` in VS Code).

Answer (score 0):

I'm investigating into using Visual Studio 2019 to develop TypeScript projects.
Mocha test runs successfully according to my test.

See https://github.com/kingsimba/NodeJS-TypeScript-in-VS2019